# how can i choose my inductance?

Tags: power, inductance, component-values

I calculated my inductance value and current rating but I can't decide which inductance I have use. for example 10uH, max 800mA my inductance values but there is other variables.in this topic I have some questions .What type of inductance should be? Multilayer,Wirewound or Molded.what Material - Core of inductance shoul be?Ferrite or Powdered Iron? how can i choose inductance? for example i want to use step down or step up converter or LC filter? what kind of situtaion i should think?
If anyone has information about this topic i will glad.
By the way i am so sorry for my english.

Comment: Please explain what it is for, what frequencies it will be used with etc.

Comment: thank you for your reply.actually this is the topic, for example i want to desing step down regulator which is switch frequency 500kHz, max current 1A. which one i choose? ferrite or iron core? how i decide that? or where i find source material
about this topic?

Answer (score 1):

Look at any switching regulator documentation... For that size, you do not need to make your own inductor, just order an already made one from Digikey or similar. Read through the TI design guide, it has all the math needed to size the inductor. It is not as easy as just 'picking' one. It is dependent on a lot of variables.

You want Ferite usually, Powder Iron is lossy at high frequency is is usually used for filters.

[TI Buck Converter Designs](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva477b/slva477b.pdf)

[Digikey - Inductors](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/inductors-coils-chokes/fixed-inductors/196627?k=inductor)

Also search this site more before asking next time:
[Calculating size of cap & inductor for buck convertor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/15260/calculating-size-of-cap-inductor-for-buck-convertor)
[LM2575 switching regulator - ideal inductor and COUT sizes](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/112925/lm2575-switching-regulator-ideal-inductor-and-cout-sizes)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, look at this booster I made using a XL6009 dc-dc ic.
[image]

According to the datasheet of this ic, a 30uh inductor rated at 4A is recommended. Thus a 30uh rated at 4A is mostly seen used with this IC. You can buy small dc-dc booster with this XL6009 very cheaply with a 30uh inductor rated at 4A in it. The problem is that this inductor will still be over-heating.

So, first rule is to determine the max current rating. For the XL6009 ic, it can handle 4A, so you need to pick a current rating higher than 4A, such as 6A. Higher rating inductor has thicker wires and is larger.

Second rule, the choice of inductance value depends largely by the switching frequency and the power output. Again, for this Xl6009, a 30uh is recommended by the IC manufacturer, but there is a trade off between size, cost and power output. Same rating inductor with same inductance will be larger in size, thus costs more. I have tested with 10uh, 30uh, 47uh, 100uh, and they all worked with this XL6009, but I decided to use a 100uh for my circuit. It's simple, and you don't need to be a mathematician or theorist to figure it out. You measure the input watts and the output watts, and you get a ratio. 100% being the best, 0% being the worst. And I found that 100uh give me better result. So the second rule is experimenting.

Third rule, there are many packages of inductors to pick from. The rule is to pick the smallest one that does the job and pick the one that looks good on the pcb. By looking good I mean 2 things: one is that this inductor will not affect other part of the circuit in a bad way, ie magnetic flux leakage. Two is that it really look good. A black smt inductor is dull on a green pcb, so I picked a golden circular inductor. It does looks good in my opinion.